# How to manually reload the Visual Studio designer for WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, designer

Is there any way to force the WPF designer to reload or refresh, without rebuilding the entire project or solution?

If there's an error, I get an option in the designer view to refresh the designer. But if I don't have an error, how can I get the designer to refresh after I've made a change?

Comment: So far, the best way of doing is by visiting some code behind file and again visiting back to the XAML file. This is poor though useful. Great question by the way. Same problem is for blend as well.

Comment: At least in theory, the Design View is always in sync with the XAML, so no need to ever refresh it manually. May I ask under which circumstances would you want to reload it?

Comment: It's been a few months now, so I can't recall the exact circumstances. It likely had to do with me making changes to data-bound listviews and listviewitems. Sometimes changing the way a datatemplate is constructed won't make it into design mode.

Comment: I have problems all the time with plain jane xaml. Nothing fancy, and suddenly, the designer stops updating. So, you're right that "in theory" it is always in sync. In practice, however, it's not. :-(

Comment: Any dynamic objects need a solution to this....

Comment: It freakin' crashes all the time. Its about as stable as an elephant balancing on a traffic cone.

Answer (score 47):

I'm a little late but this is the best solution<sup>1</sup> I've found so far: whenever the designer does stupid stuff, I just kill it's process.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>
Navigate to the Processes tab.
Kill **`XDesProc.exe`**

This also fixes issues for the properties window (like when it gets jammed and you can't type stuff into it).

<sup>1</sup> This is a solution for designer issues. Your issues may also be caused by compilation problems, in which case just right click on the solution in the solution explorer, and clean it. The reason behind it is that sometimes the compilation loses synchronicity with the generated files from XAML, and cleaning the solution just deletes those intermediate files; it's like a reset so your compilation can start off with a clean slate.

---

To do it fast:

Comfortably it's usually the last one if sorted alphabetically.
When it is, it's almost like a ritual for me to quickly pop up the task manager, click any process, press <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> (done), <kbd>Esc</kbd> (exit task manager). Instead of restarting VS and waiting for all the loads & unloads, you can do that in 1-2 seconds.

Comment: Or build a batch file and configure it to start as admin always: `TASKKILL /IM XDesProc.exe /F`

Comment: This is hilarious. You figured it out exactly as I would have done it (had I not found this solution first): Kill the process. Then you went ahead and explained it exactly as it makes sense to developers: A quick combination of keystrokes to get around some annoying bug. Always good for melting the minds of someone you're showing your unfinished product to. +1

Comment: This is super awesome!! Thank you so much! saved a lot of time of mine:)

Comment: Awesome. Just set a shortcut/hotkey automation with some proprietary and profit.

Answer (score 25):

In newer versions of Visual Studio there is an icon on the bottom of the designer to "Disable Project code". If you toggle this off and on it will reload the designer.

Comment: This is a more elegant and less hackish solution...to an ironically inelegant and hackish product

Answer (score 24):

You can add this to the `Tools` menu in Visual Studio.

Once configured, use `Tools..XAML Designer Restart`:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then <kbd>L</kbd>

[image]

[image]

I tried configuring it for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd> but this clashed with `Tools..Choose ToolboX Items`.

### Update

These days, I prefer to just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to bring up the process manager, then <kbd>X</kbd> to skip to `XDesProc.exe` then <kbd>Delete</kbd> to kill the rogue process(es).

Comment: Win10 PC, couldn't find XDesProc.exe in the Task Manager processes list but this method still worked for me. +1

Comment: @Contango What is the full path for the default installation of the initial directory?

Comment: @xtreampb From memory, it's the default. As long as `taskkill.exe` is somewhere in the path, it will work. You can try running this from a cmd prompt to see if its installed.

Comment: Then you might open Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard and for command "Tools.ExternalCommand{x}" set a shortcut, where {x} is a position of your menu in "External Tools" window.

Answer (score 7):

The Visual Studio designer attempts to keep the rendered view in sync with the XAML.  That's the advertised behavior.

- The first thing you should check is that there are no errors in the errors window.  It may be something as simple as a missing angle bracket.
- The second thing to check is whether you have any code (other than your code-behind) which needs to be compiled for the designer to render your XAML correctly.  This includes any of your own datatypes that you instantiate in XAML, any custom controls you have written (e.g. MyTextBlock derived from TextBlock), or any classes directly or indirectly in support of design-time data.  If so, you need to rebuild your project.
- The last thing to check for is possible bugs in the designer.  In spite of the advertised behavior, the designer may get out-of-sync due to bugs.  In that close, close the XAML window and re-open it.  Other tricks that might work are selecting the XAML tab and then the Design tab, or maximizing the XAML pane.

As far as rebuilding your application goes, you don't need to do this as a habit.  You only need to recompile it when the above conditions apply.  Once they don't apply, you can just edit the XAML.  Another way to say this is that if you haven't modified code, you shouldn't need to rebuild (modulo bugs).

Comment: Your second bullet point is an excellent: If the XAML I write depends on code that must be compiled, and that compiled code changes in any way, then there's no alternative to rebuilding the project. The problem is partly due to my personal workflow; I  frequently jump between editing user controls, code behind, and XAML during a single programming session.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but I think a build will refresh your view in that situation.

Comment: Yes, it will. But if I need to build the project or solution in order to see my changes in the designer, I might as well ignore the designer altogether and simply run the app itself!

Comment: @dthrasher Well for me, the application I'm working on takes several seconds to load in all it's data. The build is much quicker. But it depends per project of course. Anyway I've noticed the designer not refreshing consistently as well, it sucks, but build is the best work around I know.

Answer (score 1):

There is any event handled in that XAML file, then mostly it will not display the design preview from Visual Studio. If you want to see the design from Visual Studio, try with Command Binding instead of event, you will see the preview.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this works in WPF editing, but with ASP.NET pages when the design view wont update i can do 2 things

1. Exit Visual Studio and restart
2. Go into source view (not split), type something and remove it (not by undoing, just delete or backspare) and save it. Then return to design view, usually the view has been updated then.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a new row of code or a new object, XAML designer is sync but I encountered non-sync behavior when a property of an object is changed.

A tricky way is that when you change a property you only need to remove a ">" character from end of an instruction then retype it.

Answer (score 1):

On the toolbar in the XAML designer, choose the "Disable project code" button to reload the designer link which stays on the right side of "Turn on snapping to snaplines".

[Disable project code in the designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igMmB.png)

If it is disabled, you can try to check the configuration manager and change processors to "Any CPU".

For projects that target ARM or X64 processors, Visual Studio cannot run project code in the designer, so the Disable project code button is disabled in the designer. Check this:

[Debug or disable project code in XAML Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/debugging-or-disabling-project-code-in-xaml-designer?view=vs-2019#to-disable-project-code-in-the-designer)

Answer (score 0):

For information, I had the same issue with the XAML Designer of Visual Studio Community 2017, i.e. sometimes the designer doesn't show anything, the easiest solution is then to close the XAML file and reopen it.

I also frequently get the exception "An Unhandled Exception has occurred - Click here to reload the designer - Details: The XAML Designer has exited unexpectedly" (the click restarts the designer successfully).

Note that, in this VS version, the process of the XAML designer is not named XDesProc.exe, but **UwpSurface.exe**. If you prefer or have to kill the process, then the designer shows the same exception as above, and you may restart it.

Answer (score 0):

use process hacker and kill the WpfSurface process (blend only)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Update for designer refresh/reload Visual Studio 2022 Xamarin, taskkill /IM java.exe