# Unable to edit XAML Property, Yellow border in VS2012

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Im trying to edit a BorderBrush (**edit:** or indeed any element that requires color picker) in the VS2012 Properties pane.

After selecting the border element in the MainWindow I select Brush > BorderBrush >Solid color brush in the property pane.

There is a yellow border around the Color Picker and RGBA values and im not able to change anything in the editor, I can enter values fine into the MainWindow Element XAML ie BorderBrush="#FF777777" I just cant set them with the property editor!

What can I do to get the editor working?

Comment: I don't use the XAML editor so I couldn't answer your question definitely, but I suspect it's related to the fact `BorderBrush` expects a `Brush` object, not a `string` object containing an RGB

Comment: @Rachel I've just tried it on a <Grid> and I still cant edit color props, seems like something's locked down. edited question to reflect this.

Comment: Is the Border element you're trying to interact with part of a control template of something? I know if you're using Blend and its yellow around something in the properties pane it means it's a Binded property inside a control template. Which is why you're able to specify it inline in the xaml.

Comment: I have the same issue.  I have a path with a gradient brush for the fill.  I am not able to edit the brush.  I can switch to a solid color brush, but can't edit that brush in the panel either.  I am not using a control template or style.  No binding of any properties for this element at all.  Same problem exists when using the vs2012 editor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only solution I have found to date is to re-start VS2012.

Comment: yep, you have to restart VS.

Answer (score 4):

In VS2015 exists button "Disable project code" above XAML Editor (Zoom, Rendering effect, Show snap grid, ..., Disable project code). This help me

Comment: Yes. And for those with an older version of VS this answer will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728995/how-to-manually-reload-the-visual-studio-designer-for-wpf