# WPF Designer crashed and stopped showing Test Data permanently

Tags: wpf, crash, designer, test-data

It happened again. My test data is not shown any more. I see only class and property names. Restarting does not help this time. Retracing neither.
I've been rewriting my whole project since that happened.
Now I tried to use Test Data class to address it from custom user controls so it would look like:

```
...d:DataContext="{Binding Source={DynamicResource TestData}, Path=Emploee}"...
//in resources
<main:TestData x:Key="TestData"/>
```

Not like it was previously:

```
...d:DataContext="{DynamicResource TestEmploee}"...
//in resources:
<shar:PVEmploee x:Key="TestEmploee" Name="Alpha" Surname="Omega" Phone="77777777" PVProfession="{DynamicResource TestProfession}"/>
<shar:PVProfession x:Key="TestProfession" Name="Some obnoxeously long profession name"/>
```

And right after those changes in this control (I've done it previously few times already to other controls, I've copied from previous project version) the designer crashed. Now I see
[this ridiculousness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeq9h.png), instead of [test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbykM.png)

I am frustrated. Am I supposed to restart it again? Or there could be some way to fix it.

Comment: [Answer to almost not realated question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18082413/5847197) actually worked well (the question was - how to crash a Designer =D ). If I kill designer in Task Manager, and click "disable running code and reload the designer" in Studio the Designer loads pretty well and controls gets populated with Test Data. But I still need to do it every time I start working. It's annoying.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer to almost not realated question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18082413/5847197) Actually worked well (the question was - how to crash a Designer =D ). If I kill designer in Task Manager, and click 2nd option in Studio. The Designer loads pretty well in a right way. All my Test Data right there. Or I found later that I can click small document icon on designer bottom to reload it with or without user code.

After a few such resets it started behaving. Marvelous!